# Modal View Controller, dismiss and pop back to view controller

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

Im trying to dismiss a ModaViewController called `C`, back to `A`. The ModalViewController is presented in `B`. Therefore the Navigation flow is A->B - (present ModalView) -> C. I am able to dismiss the `ModalViewController` back to B, but I am unable to pop back to A in the completion bracket. This is the code I have tried:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
}];
```

The ModalViewController is dismissed but does not pop back to A. I call this block of code in an `IBAction`.

Any advice?

On a second note, when I dismiss the `ModalViewController` all my `UIPickers` in Controller `B` are empty/ deallocated. I am using ARC as well.

Comment: This method, in which controller is it called? A, B or C ?

Comment: @DuricanRadu its called in `C` which is the ModalViewController

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with your code is that self.navigationController will be nil. If you have a controller (A) embedded in a navigation controller, and that controller pushes to another controller (B) which then presents your last controller (C), then you need to do something like this,

```
-(IBAction)dismissToBThenPop:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [nav popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Even though you present C from B, the actual presentingViewController will be the navigation controller. This code will dismiss C then pop B, but you will see B for an instant before ut pops back to A. If you don't want to see this, then you should use an unwind segue to go directly back to A from C.

Your second problem about the pickers being empty and deallocated should not be happening under the scenario that you say you have. You will have to provide more information about what you're doing in B to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a protocol in ModalViewController, let's say ModalViewControllerDelegate with a method -(void)dismissTheModal, and make B implement this protocol. Before showing the ModalViewController, do modalViewController.delegate = self. When you're IBAction is called, do [self.delegate dismissTheModal], and in controller B you should do :

```
 -(void)dismissTheModal {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
         [self popViewController];
  }];
```